# Django rest authentication with email verification redirect to flutter app

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, dj-rest-auth

How can I redirect a user to the mobile app developed in flutter after he has confirmed the authentication link sent by email? I need the token included in the link (same for password reset).
Right now it takes me back to the django rest page.
I am using dj-rest-auth and allauth to handle authentication in django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use deep linking and dynamic links,

[image]

here the docs from firebase: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/overview/

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for Deep linking:
[this URL](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking)

and you can useunit_links package
[this pacakge](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links)